# Ternary operator to set element style trims result string

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'm working on an old web application using JSPs. In one of the pages, I set the style of table rows like so:

```
<TR id="row<%=i%>" CLASS=<%=(count%2 == 0)? "row" : "row1"%> STYLE=<%=(removed)? "display:none;" : "display:inline; font-size:20px;"%> onclick="userclickhandler(this, <%=i%>)" onkeydown="upDown(event, form1)">
```

In the browser, it shows up like this:

```
<tr id="row1" class="row" style="display:inline;" font-size:20px; onclick="userclickhandler(this, 1)" onkeydown="upDown(event, form1)">
```

The font-size setting is being left out of the style string. Why is that?

Comment: I'm not a JSP dev, but I wonder if there's a way to put quotes inside quotes?  Something like: `<TR CLASS="<%=(removed)? 'display: none;' : 'display: inline; font-size: 20px' %>"` If not that, maybe escaping the inner quotes with a `\`?

Comment: That code should work already tried on my end .Can you remove that space you have between `display:inline; font-size:20px;"` and see onces